# FTP::connection() randomly fails

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ftp, cpanel

I am using laravel and there is an FTP::connection() that reads files from a different cPanel account on the server (Linux,cPanel).

I am running a test where I try to read a 100 files. The first time it works without error, when I refresh it starts failing on multiple files.

```
public function connection() {
        Config::set('ftp.connections.key', array(
            'host'   => 'MYDOMAIN',
            'username' => $this->username,
            'password'   => decrypt($this->password),
            'passive'   => true,
            'ssl'=>true,
            'port'=>22,
         ));
        return FTP::connection();
}
```

I tried disabling the passive mode.
I tried using the 21 port with SSL disabled.
I have also tried to set a timeout value.

All did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The firewall or security section of the server you are connecting to may block your prompt requests.

Please submit requests more time and announce the result

Comment: I disabled the firewall on the server, tested with pure-ftpd server settings and issue was not solved.